# Amplify Datastore - Toggle Subscriptions Per App Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-datastore

We have a CRM built with amplify which uses Datastore with AppSync via the GraphQL option.  Our schema is quite large, and includes models for the admin portion of the CRM.  We also are building mobile apps with the same api but have no way around toggling subscriptions on and off for specific models.  The mobile apps only need a subset of the models, so the time spent setting up subscriptions is a waste on startup.

Is there any way to toggle off subscriptions on a per app, per model basis?  We already use the selective sync feature, but even whent setting those to id.eq(null), it will still start the subscriptions (it does not sync down any data, but tries) which is costly when starting up the datastore.

Any help would be appreciated.